# Is there set comparsion operation for C#?

Tags: c#, comparison, set

I have the following while statement:

```
while ((leftSide.Count-rightSide.Count!=-1)&&(leftSide.Count-rightSide.Count!= 0))
{
     // Do stuff here
}
```

I would love to write this something like this:

```
while (leftSide.Count - rightSide.Count ! in [-1, 0])
{
     // Do stuff here
}
```

but that is illegal syntax.  I am wondering, is there some way to that?  Some syntax I don't know?

I want to see if the difference of the counts in a set of numbers without having to re-include the whole left side of the statement again?

I suppose I could do this:

```
int x = leftSide.Count-rightSide.Count;
while ((x != -1) && (x != 0))
{
     // Do stuff here
     x = leftSide.Count-rightSide.Count;
}
```

but I would rather not.

If there is no way to do a "set" comparison does anyone **know why**?  C# is such a full featured language that it seems odd to have something like this missing.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973916/linq-where-in-collection-clause

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using extension methods, you could easily create an `In` operator:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static Boolean In<T>(this T obj, params T[] items)
    {
        return items.Contains(obj);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Int32 i = 10;
i.In(10, 20, 30); // True
```

Comment: Very very nice!  Using the `params` makes it really usable.

Comment: Added that to my extension methods class and now my `while` looks like this:

Comment: I wrote about this in my blog.  http://www.thecodepage.com/post.aspx?id=28197601-0cae-48a2-aadf-992e073f8690

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't need to be in the *language*, because it can easily be in a *library*:

```
private static readonly int[] ValidValues = { -1, 0 };

...

if (!ValidValues.Contains(leftSide.Count - rightSide.Count))
{
    ...
}
```

I've used an array here because it's so small... but you would want to consider using a `HashSet<int>` for a large collection.

Comment: Once again, you are the king of the quick-draw. Well played Mr. Skeet, well played.

Comment: OK, I can use that.  I come from a Delphi background where this was part of the language.  I guess I just assumed it should be a language level feature in C# too.

Answer (score 1):

```
new[]{0,1}.Contains(leftSide.Count - rightSide.Count)
```

Comment: This is probably the best C# way to do it.  I went with the extension method because it reads a bit better to me. (With my delphi background)

Answer (score 0):

```
.Contains
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HashSet` (or anything implementing ISet) to do set comparisons. For your purposes, this is overkill.

I suspect that using x>0 would work for your example though.

Answer (score 0):

For larger amounts, you can declare a `List<T>` and use the `Contains` method:

```
List<int> values = new List<int> {-1, 0};

if(!values.Contains(x))
  //do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Use extension methods:

```
public static class DoubleInExtension
{
    public static bool IsIn(this double x, double a, double b)
    {
        return x >= a && x <= b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] set = {-1, 0};
while (!set.Contains(leftSide.Count - rightSide.Count))
{
//Do stuff here
}
```